# Submit of custom node with imagefield ends without warning after imagefield save

Tags: nodes, entities, 6, media

I have a custom Drupal node type with a bunch of text fields, a taxonomy-dropdown and an imagefield. Only the title is mandatory, all other fields are optional. I have added no custom code that should interfere with the form being processed.

When I submit the filled-out form to add a node of this type, the form reloads without adding the node and without displaying any kind of error message. When I leave the title blank, the expected error is displayed.

**EDIT/UPDATE**

I have started reconstructing the content type and found out that the imagefield seems to be the culprit. The node will save flawlessly if the the type does not have an imagefield.

The minute I add the imagefield, saving fails. The image will even be uploaded, thumbnails will be displayed, but then the form will reappear with no further message.

Answer (score 1):

The issue had something to do with duplicate translations for button labels that basically lead to only the file field being submitted when saving the node, see: http://drupal.org/node/684426 A simple update of the localization files solves the problem and makes you hate Drupal just a teensy bit.